# How does Google Chrome control/contain multiple processes?

Tags: google-chrome, process

How does Google Chrome command and control multiple cross platform processes and provide a shared window / rendering area?

Any insights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code is online [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/chromium/+/trunk/chrome/) ...

Answer (score 7):

There is a document called [Multi-process Architecture](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/multi-process-architecture) on the Chromium developer site. It might be a good starting place.